# Office JS: Roaming settings intermittently returns undefined for a given key

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We store some business relevant data on **RoamingSettings** exposed by [Outlook's OfficeJs API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.roamingsettings?view=outlook-js-1.8) for our add-in. We persist this in the form of key value pairs as shown below:

```
Office.context.mailbox.roamingSettings.set(key, value)
Office.context.mailbox.roamingSettings.saveAsync()
```

We retreive the value saved on the roaming setting as below:

```
var value = Office.context.mailbox.roamingSettings.get(key)
```

We observed that for some of our customers, this value is intermittently being returned as `undefined` for a given key. It works fine for others.

**[EDIT]**

**The chain of events observed in a call with the customer:**

1. User opens the taskpane and the settings value is retrieved
2. User closes the taskpane and opens it again
3. The roaming settings value persists
4. The user closes and opens the taskpane again
5. The roaming settings value is not found (undefined)
6. The user closes and opens the taskpane again several times
7. The roaming settings value is eventually found

**Windows Build version:**

[image: Windows Version]

**Outlook Build Version:**

[image: Outlook Version]

Is there anyone else experiencing this ?
Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: "Any changes made to settings using the set function will not be saved to the server until the saveAsync function is called." Maybe caused by this?

Comment: Is there any consitancies to the intermittent success/failure cases? For example, "All the successes are on Chrome" or "All the failures are in the Win32 Desktop client"?

Comment: @Lumpenstein, we do use the saveAsync method to save the settings to server. Edited my question.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, We have observed this issue only on Win32 Desktop Client so far. The customer also mentioned that he saw an alert saying that the add-in had to restart because it was not responding. The settings seem to have cleared after the add-in restarted.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, I got a message from the customer experiencing this issue today. He says that he is on Win64 machine. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Has this only happened for this one user, or there other users who've experienced this issue? There's a known limitation of Roaming Settings that if the task pane navigates to another page or reloads the current page (which is what sounds like what happened for your user), the in-memory object is reset to its initial values, even if your add-in has persisted changes. The persisted changes will not be available until the task pane is closed and reopened. You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.roamingsettings?view=outlook-js-preview)

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response, we have only one customer experiencing this. And they mentioned that the add-in doesn't reload when this issue occurs. The user does have the taskpane pinned in their client. Could that be related to the roaming settings getting cleared ? Any other reasons why they might be running into this issue ?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Is there any feedback for my comment above? I appreciate your help in this regard.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Adding Windows and Outlook build version for reference.
Outlook version: 16.0.11929.20708
Windows version: 10.0.18363 Build 18363